# append rows from a 'for loop' to a dataframe using pd.concat with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

After an update, I am getting the following message:

**'The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.'**

I am having trouble re-writing my code with **pd.concat()** instead of **df.append()**. Please help!

I am conducting an artificial star experiment, where I have three files with columns:

b1: ['Id', 'x', 'y', 'bmag'] - artificial stars with b-filter

i1: ['Id', 'x', 'y', 'imag'] - artificial stars with I-filter

biart: ['Id', 'x', 'y', 'bmag', 'imag'] - measured stars

**I have calculated the minimum radial distance between stars in b1 (artificial) and biart (measured) by keeping the 'Id', 'bmag' and 'imag' for both files if the minimum distance is satisfied.**

```
extract = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Id_art', 'x_art', 'y_art', 
                                  'bmag_art', 'imag_art', 
                                  'dist_d',
                                  'Id_meas', 'x_meas', 'y_meas',                                 
                                  'bmag_meas', 'imag_meas'])

for i in range(len(b1.index)):
    
    x = b1['x'].iloc[i]
    y = b1['y'].iloc[i]
    
    dist = np.sqrt((x - biart['x'])**2 + (y - biart['y'])**2)
    
    if (min(dist))<=1/2:
        
        print(b1['Id'].iloc[i], 
              b1['x'].iloc[i], 
              b1['y'].iloc[i],        
              b1['bmag'].iloc[i], 
              i1['imag'].iloc[i], 
              min(dist),
              biart['Id'].iloc[dist.idxmin()],
              biart['x'].iloc[dist.idxmin()],
              biart['y'].iloc[dist.idxmin()], 
              biart['bmag'].iloc[dist.idxmin()],
              biart['imag'].iloc[dist.idxmin()])
            
        extract = extract.append({'Id_art': b1['Id'].iloc[i],
                                    'x_art':b1['x'].iloc[i], 
                                   'y_art': b1['y'].iloc[i], 
                                 'bmag_art':b1['bmag'].iloc[i],
                                 'imag_art':i1['imag'].iloc[i],
                                   'dist_d':min(dist), 
                         'Id_meas':biart['Id'].iloc[dist.idxmin()], 
                          'x_meas':biart['x'].iloc[dist.idxmin()],
                          'y_meas':biart['y'].iloc[dist.idxmin()], 
                     'bmag_meas':biart['bmag'].iloc[dist.idxmin()],
                    'imag_meas':biart['imag'].iloc[dist.idxmin()]},
                                     ignore_index=True)
```

**how do I rewrite the code below to pd.concat()?**

```
extract.append({'Id_art': b1['Id'].iloc[i],
                  'x_art':b1['x'].iloc[i], 
                 'y_art': b1['y'].iloc[i],
               'bmag_art':b1['bmag'].iloc[i],
               'imag_art':i1['imag'].iloc[i],
               'dist_d':min(dist),
               'Id_meas':biart['Id'].iloc[dist.idxmin()], 
                'x_meas':biart['x'].iloc[dist.idxmin()],
                'y_meas':biart['y'].iloc[dist.idxmin()], 
             'bmag_meas':biart['bmag'].iloc[dist.idxmin()],
             'imag_meas':biart['imag'].iloc[dist.idxmin()]},
                                     ignore_index=True)

``
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the dataframe to a list, and have the `pd.DataFrame` constructor consume the list at the end:

```py
# Make a list first
extract = []

for i in range(len(b1.index)):
    
    x = b1['x'].iloc[i]
    y = b1['y'].iloc[i]
    
    dist = np.sqrt((x - biart['x'])**2 + (y - biart['y'])**2)
    
    if (min(dist))<=1/2:
        
        print(b1['Id'].iloc[i], b1['x'].iloc[i], b1['y'].iloc[i],        
              b1['bmag'].iloc[i], i1['imag'].iloc[i], 
              min(dist),
              biart['Id'].iloc[dist.idxmin()],
              biart['x'].iloc[dist.idxmin()],
              biart['y'].iloc[dist.idxmin()], 
              biart['bmag'].iloc[dist.idxmin()],
              biart['imag'].iloc[dist.idxmin()])
            
        # Append to the list here
        extract.append({'Id_art': b1['Id'].iloc[i],
                                      'x_art':b1['x'].iloc[i], 
                                      'y_art': b1['y'].iloc[i], 
                                      'bmag_art':b1['bmag'].iloc[i],
                                      'imag_art':i1['imag'].iloc[i],
                                      'dist_d':min(dist), 
                            'Id_meas':biart['Id'].iloc[dist.idxmin()], 
                              'x_meas':biart['x'].iloc[dist.idxmin()],
                              'y_meas':biart['y'].iloc[dist.idxmin()], 
                        'bmag_meas':biart['bmag'].iloc[dist.idxmin()],
                       'imag_meas':biart['imag'].iloc[dist.idxmin()]})
```

Then, after the loop is finished filling the list:

```py
# Consume the data here
extract = pd.DataFrame(extract)
```

Comment: Can you please clarify how I would append with pd.concat() ?